# Using Outlook forms data with Microsoft Exchange Power Query

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices

So I have made an outlook appointment form with custom data fields for calendar entries and those data fields do not appear when I uses Microsoft exchange to run a on the account. Is there something I need to do with outlook forms to make their data fields appear in Microsoft exchange queries?